# Backslash behaviour in different versions of postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have to run a series of queries on different versions of PostgreSQL (from 8.3 to 9.6), and I'm having issues with the backslash character because in the 8.x versions it needs to be escaped, in the 9.x versions it does not.

At the moment I run the query `SELECT '\\'` and check whether the result is `"\"` or `"\\"` so that I know if the backslash needs escaping or not.

I was wondering if there's some way, through a query, to tell postgres to treat backslashes always the same way (without tinkering with its configuration, because I do not have access to the configuration of these installations).

Comment: First, all Postgres versions 9.5 and lower are past EOL and 9.6 is going EOL November 2021. There are/will be no bug/security fixes for these, so escaping issues may well be the least of your issues. Second, try [Escape syntax](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-STRINGS-ESCAPE): `select E'\\'; \`

Comment: That's exactly why I'm extracting all data from those databases :)

Comment: Then why not use the recent version of `pg_dump` to grab the data from the older Postgres databases?

Comment: Because we're transferring on a different database, so all the data needs to be reformatted and adapted to the new environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior is governed by the parameter `standard_conforming_strings`, which was introduced in version 8.2.
In version 9.1, the default value of that parameter was changed to `on`.

If `standard_conforming_strings` is `off`, the backslash is an escape character in string literals.

You can change the parameter for the database session using the `SET` SQL statement, and there is no need to change the configuration. An alternative is to always use &ldquo:extended” string literals (with a leading `E` in front of the starting single quote) – in such literals the backslash is always an escape character:

```
SELECT E'\\';

 ?column? 
══════════
 \
(1 row)
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for!